# What does "I’ll show you to [somewhere]" mean?

Tags: meaning, speech

I read a dialogue in English and saw a strange phrase.

> A: Good afternoon. May I help you?
>   B: Yes, I’m here to see Joanna Stevens. I have an appointment at four.
>   ...
>   ...
>   A: Ms. Stevens is ready for you now. I’ll show you to her office, right this way.

I really don't understand what "I’ll show you to her office" means. Why should office know about her?

Why not "I'll show you where her office is"? Or something like that. Is this kind of mistake? Or does it really means something?

Comment: This probably belongs on ELL.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The meaning of "show" here is [number four,](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/show?s=t) meaning "to guide, escort, or usher."

An usher in a theater might **show** you to your seats.

A bellboy in a hotel might **show** you to your room.

In your scenario, Ms. Stevens, hearing from the receptionist that you have arrived, might tell the receptionist "Please **show** him in." After your conversation, she might ask the receptionist to **show** you out.

Comment: "here is number five" - number four %)  .....Thank you. It so much clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right, it means *"I'll show you where her office is"*, and in context of the narrative, it also implies that *Person A* will likely walk with the visitor, *Person B*, to Joanna Steven's office, if it isn't in the immediate vicinity.

In no way is any personification of the *"office"* implied in this phrase - it is merely the intended destination.

A similar phrase is to *Show someone (to) the door*, which means to ask someone to leave, or to eject someone from the building.

*Re : Why should office know about her?*

You may be confusing this with the phrase ['show you *off* to {Person}'](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/show-sth-sb-off) - in this context, the meaning shifts to one of pride in the subject (you), to the point where the speaker wishes to brag about {you} to {Person}. This may be because of a recent achievement of {you}, a physical attribute of {you} such as beauty, or any other reason which would attribute pride in the speaker. The motive here is likely for the speaker's own personal advancement (through social association to {you}), and not necessarily in the best interest of {you}.